# Python3, FastAPI, and Firebase: Not able to do ref.get() from firebase successfully

Tags: python, rest, firebase-realtime-database, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have been using firebase realtime database recently and I am not sure as to why when I create a database reference in python, I can not simply get the data at that location. In the IPython, I can do the following successfully:

```py
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth, initialize_app, db

cred = credentials.Certificate("my_certificate.json")
initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL':'link_to_my_database'})

ref = db.reference("some_text_here")
print(ref.get())

>>> desired output
```

But when I put this code in my REST API code (using FastAPI), I get a "None" value. I know firebase for python is a blocking I/O, but I don't understand how that could be affecting my code if everything is working in IPython? I would really appreciate any help in showing me where I need to fix my code. I'm not sure if I should just switch to Node.js because of this blocking I/O stuff with Python

---

**Update (June 28, 2020)**

Based on a comment on the question I have added my FastAPI code below to show where I am having issues:

Router.py

```py
import asyncio
from app.controllers.pyController import PyController

async def new_func(some_data: str, udata:dict):
eventLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
  eventLoop.run_until_complete(PyController().pyController_func(some_data, udata, eventLoop))
finally:
  print("maybe we're done?")
```

pyController.py

```py
import redis
from app.services.runPyService import RunPyService

class PyController:
  async def pyController_func(self, some_data, uData, eventLoop):
    r = redis.Redis()
    dStoreVal = r.hget(some_data, "data")
    done = await RunPyService().runPyService_func(dStoreVal, uData, eventLoop)
```

runPyService.py

```py
from firebase_admin import db
import asyncio
import concurrent

class RunPyService:
  executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=40)
 
  async def runPyService_func(self, dStoreVal, uData, eventLoop):
    coroutine = [self.getData(dStoreVal, eventLoop)]
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutine)
    for item in completed:
       print(item.result())

  async def getData(self, dStoreVal, eventLoop):
    ref = db.reference("where-data-is-located")
    return await eventLoop.run_in_executor(self.executor, ref.get)
```

I am passing the `eventLoop` that I get from the router through the controller to the service where I actually use it. Usually, at this point in my code I get an error saying, `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. This is usually because my `getData()` returns none. `Ref.get()` never actually gets the data at that location.

Comment: Try posting also your fastapi code. Otherwise it is not possible to help

Comment: ok! I posted the FastAPI code above as an update. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I believe that the problem is in the `firebase_admin's db` that you import. It has not been initialized. Still, post also the error with the line of code and there reference code that causes the error, otherwise it is difficult to understand the problem if one can only say from your guesses

Comment: My `firebase_admin's db` has been initialized in another file. If I put that initialize code in my `RunPyService` I will get (and have gotten) `ValueError: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initialize_app() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initialize_app() to give each app a unique name.` error. That leads me to think that is not the problem

Comment: Sorry, can't comment if I don't see all of the code. Anyway, do you mind posting the error log? It's difficult to spot what is causing the error with such information

Comment: Where did you get instruction or understanding of using the controller pattern in python? curious...

Comment: @SirVon no problem -> https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/building-a-rest-api-using-python-fastapi-and-heroku-b7e9341f578